# home navlinks link stay active REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I hoe you are doing well :)

when I click on a link from the navbar, the home link is always active. I tried to add excat to the home route but nothing changed?
if someone can help me please that would be great.

thank you in advance
thank you for your time

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { links } from "../utils/constants";
import styled from "styled-components";

const NavMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <ul>
        {links.map((link) => {
          const { id, url, text } = link;
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <NavLink to={url}>{text}</NavLink>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Nav>
  );
};

const Nav = styled.nav`
  ////////
    .active {
      color: var(--white);
    }
  }
`;

export default NavMenu;
```

APP.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { NavMenu } from "./components";
import { Home, About, Projects, Contact, Error } from "./pages";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavMenu />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/projects">
          <Projects />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <Error />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using Route Component properly. You should try in this way.
Pass the path and component in the Route instead of wrapping it inside in Route component.

```
import { HomePage, UserPage } from "./pages";
    const routes = [
            {
                path: '/home',
                component: HomePage,
            },
            {
                path: '/user',
                component: UserPage,
            }]
    
    <Switch>
            {routes.map(({ path, component }, index) => (
                <Route key={String(index)} exact path={path} component={component} />
            ))}
    </Switch>
```

Comment: thank you so much! you taught me something new.‍

Comment: @AM No worries. Let me know if there is still some confusion on your end  :)